# How to differentiate between an admin and a user in the api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express framework , Lets say I have this line in the API :

```
router.delete('/user',(req, res) => { //deleting...}
```

Now I want that only an Admin will be able to access this line.

In the rest of the code there are lines that only user can access like :

```
router.put('/post')
```

And lines only  admin can access like:

```
router.put('/killDB)
```

what is the best way (tokens, sessions or something like that) that will be able to help me differenitate between the two?

Comment: I use [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use password to authenticate users and then check if the user is an admin. And then simply add password logic to your route. Below I will provide my code where I just check if user is logged in (it was enough for me)

```
router.get('/delete', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
Page.collection.drop();
var page = new Page();
page.save(function (err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.redirect('/admin');
    });
});

// render login form
router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
   res.render('login',{ message: req.flash('error'), layout: null});
});

// process the login form
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/admin', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

// if they aren't redirect them to the home page
res.redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **connect-roles** package to authorize your users, and then route them to those URL's which they are allowed to access.

You can also opt for **passport.js**, however it is more or like a **authentication package** where as the **connect-roles** just aims at to provide only the "**authorization**" part. And this package works well with Express.

Once you implement this package, you can use the "role" attribute to check the user's authorization level and allow them to perform their respective actions.

For eg.,

```
if (req.user.role === 'admin')  {
   router.put('/killDB)
}
```

You can check out the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-roles

Hope this helps!